# How to get the children count of a folder with Google Drive APIs?

Tags: c#, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client, google-drive-android-api

I'm using the Google Drive v3 APIs and I'm having some trouble getting the number of elements in a given folder.

Right now I'm using the List API with the following query string:

> 'MyFolderId' in parents

Here's the code I'm using (.NET client library):

```
async Task<int> GetChildrenCountAsync(String folderId)
{
    FilesResource.ListRequest childrenRequest = Drive.Files.List();
    request.Fields = "files";
    request.Q = $"'{folderId}' in parents  and trashed = false";
    FileList children = await childrenRequest.ExecuteAsync();
    return children?.Files.Count() ?? 0;
}
```

I'm also using "files" in the "fields" property of the API. This way I get a list of all the files in the folder, I count them and that's it.

The issue though is that this approach is really inefficient - *I only want to know the number of children of a folder*, nothing else.

Plus, if a folder has too many items, this way I'd have eventually perform multiple queries to retrieve all the results, and I'd waste a considerable amount of data and time.

Is there a way to just **query the number of children of a folder**?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @ParagJadhav I've updated my question with a code sample, I hadn't put it there in the first place since it's using a code wrapper library and not the API directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no children counter for items inside the drive storage because folders in drive api do not act as regular folders in desktops.

Comment: I get it, but is there a way to just query the items with "'id' in parents" and have the server/API just return their number instead of the whole list?
I mean, if I had a folder with 1000+ items it'd take too much to load all those items just to be able to count them.